# Grouping cells in Google sheet possible?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-finance

Is there a certain method (would be better if it doesn't require some custom script) that I can create a group for a list of cells? So that I don't have to click-to-select every time, there are like 100 cells in total non-adjacent/non-consecutive to each other.

These 100 cells I mentioned above supposed to be for a importxml formula, that require an update by the end of each month. So I would really prefer to have just the data itself in these cells, instead of having it to fetch with a formula everytime and slow down the sheet.

So I'm looking if I can create some sort of grouped cells that I can quickly swap between formula & just the data.

**A bit of info, I can't change how the cells are arranged, because I'm using the range function + OFFSET to locate the data into another worksheet, so the data has to be in that layout.

Thank you!

Comment: Is there any pattern to the cells or are they pretty random? Can you provide a simplified example plz to give us an idea what your data looks like? - see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: What exactly do you want to do with that list of cells once a month? If you can give a small example with 10 cells it would help to visually interpret your problem.